# How to send Firebase token to Wordpress plugin (missing os parameter)

Tags: android, wordpress

I'm trying to connect posts from a Wordpress website using the Wordpress plugin and Firebase for cloud messaging. So whenever there's a new post in the website, the app users will receive a notification about it First, I need to send an API POST request with the device's token to the plugin. Ex:

URL structure:
http://yoursite/pnfw/register/

Method:
POST

Parameters:
token (string): token given by APNs or FCM identifying the device, often called device ID (read here for devices without token, e.g. iOS simulator).
os (string): operating system. It must be iOS or Android (case sensitive).

--Sample request for new registration:
POST /pnfw/register/ HTTP/1.1
Host: yoursite
Content-Length: 26
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

token=new_device_id&os=iOS

It is working when I test the API, but Android Studio keeps sending me this response:

> 2021-06-16 16:18:20.488 24664-24664/com.bc.brendan.soccernbandroidapp
> I/ResponseMsg: {"error":"500","reason":"Internal Server
> Error","detail":"Mandatory parameter os missing"}

Debug:

> Request{method=POST,
> url=https://myWebSite.org/appdev/pnfw/register?token=fiCob....cdJmg2&os=Android,
> tags={class
> retrofit2.Invocation=com.bc.brendan.myApp.JsonPlaceholderAPI.createRegister()
> [fiCob...cdJmg2, Android]}}

CODE for Firebase Class

```
package com.bc.brendan.myApp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.Query;

public class FirebasePush extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public FirebasePush() {
        super();
    }

    private String newToken;
    private JsonPlaceholderAPI jsonPlaceholderAPI;


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@androidx.annotation.NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token) {
        super.onNewToken(token);
        Log.e("newToken", token);
        newToken = token;

        sendToken();
    }
    

    private void sendToken() {
        Register register = new Register(newToken, "Android");

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://myWebSite.org/appdev/pnfw/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        jsonPlaceholderAPI = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderAPI.class);

        Call<Register> call = jsonPlaceholderAPI.createRegister(register.getToken(), register.getOs());

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Register>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Register> call, Response<Register> response) {
                try {
                    Log.i("ResponseMsg", response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Register> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("ErrorMsg", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send parameters in URL encoded form (in the body) as you can see in the example you have pasted:

> Sample request for new registration: POST /pnfw/register/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: yoursite Content-Length: 26 Content-Type:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> token=new_device_id&os=iOS

Comment: That was exactly what I was missing. Thank you! I just changed the Retrofit interface and it worked.                                                                                                         
               @FormUrlEncoded
               @POST("register")
    Call<Register> createRegister(@Field("token") String token,
                                                     @Field("os") String os);

Comment: Perfect! I suggest you to mark this answer as accepted.